# Azure functions project deployed in local server

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I need to deploy an azure functions project written in C# language in a local server for test purpose, before deploying it in Azure.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the oficial docker image, but the experience will be totally different:

https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-azure-functions-base

You can also use the local development tools